# Displaying Image on VGA and/or Television through ARM Micro controllers(in C)(SD Card)

Tags: arm, microcontroller, sd-card, vga

I worked on 8051 micro controllers, a few months before, and found it quite interesting. Had a few projects, enjoyed while programming. I picked a project with the above title as my final project this year in my college. I am not much sure if i would be able to do it, so i need your help. Where should I start from, I know a little about ARM Micro-controllers. Interfacing SD Card wouldn't be a problem, in fact i would add a static ram too, but working with pictures and up to 16 bits per pixel, looks like huge to me. Suggest me, where should i start from, the most difficult part, as I guess, on my project is processing the image to show on VGA. Suggest me, anything you can.
My personal email address is taha_rehman@writeme.com. Every suggestion is welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [SoftVGA](http://neil.franklin.ch/Projects/SoftVGA)
2. [TinyVGA](http://tinyvga.com)
3. [AvrVGA](http://www.serasidis.gr/circuits/AVR_VGA/avr_vga.htm)
4. [Tellymate](http://www.batsocks.co.uk/products/Other/TellyMate.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [RBox](http://rossum.posterous.com/20131601). It's TV signal, not VGA, but is very simple to implement. VGA is trickier but [possible too](http://www.jandspromotions.com/philips2005/Winners/AR1784.htm). Check also [this discussion](http://mbed.org/forum/mbed/topic/186/) with more comments and links (about mbed, but the points generally apply to most ARM chips).